# windows api request for lpSystemPowerStatus always shows 0 power

Tags: c++, winapi, window

Can anyone gander as to why this is always false?

```
    SYSTEM_POWER_STATUS lpSystemPowerStatus;
    GetSystemPowerStatus(&lpSystemPowerStatus);
    int charging = (lpSystemPowerStatus.BatteryFlag & BATTERY_FLAG_CHARGING) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: You are not checking to see whether `GetSystemPowerStatus()` is succeeding or failing. It returns a `BOOL`: "*If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero. If the function fails, the return value is zero.*". What is the actual return value? If it is succeeding, you are only looking for 1 flag out of several possible flag values. What is the actual value of `BatteryFlag`?

Comment: Are you running this on a computer that has a battery? Is the battery actually charging and not full? Finally, What *is* the value of BatteryFlag? Inspect it :)

Comment: Also, you are not initializing `lpSystemPowerStatus`, so if `GetSystemPowerStatus(...)` fails, you may be inspecting garbage data.

Answer (score 0):

I had to `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0400` before `#include "Windows.h"`.

Credit:
http://www.cpp-home.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=5533